Poetry using a lot of disk space in GitHub Actions
I'm using GitHub Actions to automate the testing and deployment of a Python project. As part of the testing CI/CD pipeline, I install the project dependencies using Poetry. To speed up the process, I cache virtual environments after installation and reuse them if
nothing has changed in the Poetry lock file. However, I've noticed that when there's no cached virtual environment available and the pipeline needs to install dependencies from scratch, disk space usage increases significantly, even if the Poetry cache is cleared afterwards. Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening and how I can prevent the extra disk space usage when installing dependencies?
For example, in this run, I have 5.6 GB of free disk space left after retrieving a cached virtual environment, whereas installing dependencies without caching left me with only 2.9 GB in this run. Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening and how I can prevent the extra disk space usage when installing dependencies? You can find the YAML file for the pipeline here.

I believe you can drop into Github Actions debug mode and us ls, df and other UNIX command line commands to explore the machine and find out what's taking the disk space.
